# How to add contact to O365 distribution list using c#?

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, distribution-list

How can I add/remove contacts to/from O365 distribution lists using C#?

In PowerShell this can be done using the commands Add-DistributionGroupMember, Remove-DistributionGroupMember from the module ExchangePowershell.

Comment: Do you mean a GAL distribution list? Or a dist list in your Contacts folder in Outlook? What API are you using?

Comment: Indeed, I need to manipulate GAL distribution lists. I would like to automate this in a C# Hangfire job.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what technology you would like to use. There are several ways to get the job done in C#:

1. Automate Outlook from your C# application. See [How To: Create a new distribution list item in Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/03/29/create-outlook-distribution-list/) for more information. Note, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.
2. Use EWS, see [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.
3. Use Graph API, see [Working with groups in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/groups-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: I need to manipulate distribution groups containing Users and Contacts - they appear in the GAL.

Comment: Have you already tried any point mentioned in my post?

Comment: Tried point 3)
Gives error 'Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException : Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Cannot Update a mail-enabled security groups and or distribution list.'

I'm afraid with Point 2) I can add OrgContacts but not Users (B2B Guest users)